# Time variable lost upon encoding URI

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, urlencode

I have been encoding a string of variables in the following format: 
http://758.d9d.myftpupload.com/confirmation/?custID=105905780&first=parker&last=ryan&email=aparkerryan27@gmail.com&token=c2734a1a-24ac-4b73-9607-4db12f60ecae&loc=29318&serviceType=sugaring&specificService=bikini&timeChosen=4%20pm%20-%204:40%20pm%20&dateTime=/Date(1477945200000-0400)/&status=signed&treatmentID=1523982&formattedDate=October%2031,%202016

The focus of this question is the timeChosen variable, which i encode (using URIencode or simply just placing that in the string of variables as the window.location.href) from a simple "4:20 pm - 4:40 pm"

which is returning the incorrect html, any idea why? (I think it has something to do with the 20 and the %20 being a space, but i dont know how to work around this)

Feel free to navigate about with the link to understand the purpose further. This problem is only occuring with the first half of the variable, and i have not been able to identify any other area where the issue could be coming from. Let me know if you need to see another section of my code and I will update my question.

Comment: I think you meant "javascript" tag, not "java" one. That's why JS people don't see your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "timeChosen" in this URL is in fact: '4 pm 20 - 4:40 pm' and it shows as "4 pm - 4:40 pm" in my Chrome that seems to be quite ok with such URL...

Check this URL

```
http://758.d9d.myftpupload.com/confirmation/?custID=105905780&first=parker&last=ryan&email=aparkerryan27@gmail.com&token=c2734a1a-24ac-4b73-9607-4db12f60ecae&loc=29318&serviceType=sugaring&specificService=bikini&timeChosen=4:20%20pm%20-%204:40%20pm%20&dateTime=/Date(1477945200000-0400)/&status=signed&treatmentID=1523982&formattedDate=October%2031,%202016
```

With this, it's fine.